# How do I calculate the variance of nearest-neighbor averaged data without explicitly averaging the data?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra

***CONTEXT:***

I have a non-symmetric, k-nearest-neighbor adjacency matrix of a directed graph, $N\in\mathcal{R}^{n \times n}$, and data $D\in\mathcal{R}^{n\times m}$. To average each of $n$ observations in $D$ with their $k$ nearest neighbors, it is simply: $$\bar{D}=\frac{1}{k} N D$$

My goal is to find the mean and variance of each of $m$ features in $\bar{D}$. However, let's say $D$ is a large, sparse matrix and I do not wish to break the sparsity structure via this averaging due to memory constraints.

Is it possible to find the mean and variance of $\bar{D}$ without explicitly computing $ND$?

The mean is just a matter of order of operations: 
$$\bar{\mu} = \frac{1}{nk}1^T(ND) = \frac{1}{nk}(1^TN)D$$
This way we do not need to explicitly calculate $ND$.

The variance is super tricky and I haven't figured out how to do it efficiently:
$$\bar{\sigma}^2 =\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{D}_i\circ \bar{D}_i\right) - \bar{\mu}^2$$ where $\bar{D}_i$ is the $i$th row of $\bar{D}$ and $\circ$ is the Hadamard product (element-wise multiplication).

$$\bar{\sigma}^2 =\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (\frac{1}{k}N_iD)\circ(\frac{1}{k}N_iD)\right) - \bar{\mu}^2$$
$$\bar{\sigma}^2 =\frac{1}{nk^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (N_iD)\circ(N_iD)\right) - \bar{\mu}^2$$ where $N_i$ is the $i$th row of $N$. To illustrate further, let's take an example for what the $i$th summand might look like:
$$(N_iD)\circ(N_iD) = (D_1+D_3+D_7+D_9+\ldots)^2$$
$$ = (D_1 \circ D_1+D_3 \circ D_3+D_7 \circ D_7+D_9 \circ D_9) + (2D_1\circ D_3+2D_1\circ D_7+\ldots)$$
Thus, we can avoid $ND$ by writing the variance as
$$\bar{\sigma}^2 =\frac{1}{nk^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n N_i(D\circ D)+2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n a_{ij}D_i\circ D_j\right) - \bar{\mu}^2$$
where $a_{ij}$ is a coefficient encoding the number of times two observations are in the same local neighborhood.
$$\bar{\sigma}^2 =\frac{1}{nk^2}(1^T N)(D\circ D)+\frac{2}{k^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n a_{ij}D_i\circ D_j\right) - \bar{\mu}^2$$

$$\boxed{\bar{\sigma}^2 =\frac{1}{nk^2}(1^T N)(D\circ D)+\frac{2}{k^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n D_i \circ\left(\sum_{j=i+1}^n a_{ij} D_j \right)\right) - \bar{\mu}^2}$$

***QUESTION:***

This is where I get stuck! The combinatorics here (the pesky $a_{ij}$) seem to be computationally prohibitive. Two questions:

1) Did I do anything wrong up to now?

2) Is there anything I missed or useful approximations / matrix calculus I can use to allow me to efficiently evaluate $\bar{\sigma}^2$ without explicitly computing $ND$?

Comment: The way $N$ has been defined $\,\frac{1}{k}({\tt1}^TN)$ is just an obfuscated way of writing ${\tt1}^T$, so the proposed mean is unchanged from the usual definition $\,\frac{1}{n}{\tt1}^TD.\;$ An example with $\,k=3,\,n=6:$
$$\eqalign{
N&=\left[\matrix{
 1&1&0&0&0&1 \\
 1&1&1&0&0&0 \\
 0&1&1&1&0&0 \\
 0&0&1&1&1&0 \\
 0&0&0&1&1&1 \\
 1&0&0&0&1&1}\right] = N^T \\
{\tt1}^TN &= \pmatrix{3&3&3&3&3&3} \\
}$$

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, but $N$ is a $k$-nearest-neighbor adjacency matrix of a directed graph. So it is not necessarily symmetric. In other words, $N\neq N^T$.

Comment: Also, even if I were to symmetrize $N$, it would be hard to enforce each node to have equal degree.